# Structure of cvMemStorage?

Tags: c, visual-c++, opencv

I am creating an application,I am trying to use `cvMemStorage`. What is the structure of `cvMemStorage`?

I have also used

```
cvFindCountour(iUnionImage,contours,&first_contour,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

here the variable first_contour is of type `CvSeq*`, whose adress will be stored here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the documentation http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html?

Comment: Yes I have already read all the documentations..But it does not explain my question..!!!